# Java - invoke a method on all values of an array without a for loop

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any comprehensive way to invoke a method on every value in a an array without having to create a for loop? It seems like it would be trivial, but I am unable to find anything.

For example:

```
class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] arr = {"1","2","3"};
        int[] intarr = new int[arr.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

is there any way to do this without a for loop?

Comment: Why would you ever need to not use a for loop? No.

Comment: _"is there any way to do this without a for loop?"_ how about `while` loop?

Comment: Assuming the answer you're looking for isn't @ImmerAllein 's "while-loop" suggestion...No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your Java version:

Pre Java 8:

```
List<String> lis = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
Iterator<String> itr = lis.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    String next = itr.next();
    //work with next
}
```

For Java 8:

```
List<String> lis = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
lis.stream().forEach((s) -> {
    //work with s
});
```

Both of which are silly and pointless considering you can very easily just do what you described in the OP. `for` loops are an integral part of programming concepts, you can't really just avoid them.

Comment: Seconded. If you think about it programmatically, regardless of structure or library, the software is going to have to iterate over the elements. A For-loop works just as well as anything else.

Comment: Note that both of these methods actually iterate through the array for you, but much less readbly and efficiently. Use a for loop.

Comment: OK that makes sense thank you guys! It just seemed kind of trivial to create a for loop that takes up several lines of code, only to to add one to a list of variables, and other things like that.

Comment: @Anubian Noob : Both methods are better than iterating via a loop. Second can also be made faster using multiple cores at the same time. So in terms of performance, although it may not seem fast now, it is suitable for performance optimizations in future.

Comment: @TanmayPatil This is one of those optimizations where it is rarely worth it... Especially for the three element array the asker provided. Still, this does answer the question very well.

Comment: generally parallelStream shouldn't be used on small datasets.  The overhead of using the fork join pool far outweighs the benefit you get from the concurrent execution of the computations.  It's only when you get to larger, more computationally expensive tasks that it begins to show benefit.